Where to find full ROS2 API documentation?
I'm a ROS 1 veteran and am currently working on my first serious ROS 2 project. I'm having trouble figuring out the details of the how the documentation is laid out. I'll provide a specific example to show my problem, but really I'm looking for general advice:
I wanted to know the details of launch.actions.append_environment_variable.
I find launch's web page in the ros index (https://index.ros.org/p/launch/github-ros2-launch/#humble).
From there I find a link to the github (https://github.com/ros2/launch)
and also a link to the "Launch documentation" https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/p/launch/
The problem is the "Launch documentation" page only has the contents of the handwritten launch/doc/source/architecture.rst and not the full generated API documentation from the code's docstrings. It provides a good overview but doesn't have all the details.
If I look at the source code for the function, I see that it contains well documented reStructuredText style docstring:
class AppendEnvironmentVariable(Action):
"""
Action that appends to an environment variable if it exists and sets it if it does not.

It can optionally prepend instead of appending.
It can also optionally use a custom separator, with the default being a platform-specific
separator, `os.pathsep`.
"""

def __init__(
    self,
    name: SomeSubstitutionsType,
    value: SomeSubstitutionsType,
    prepend: Union[bool, SomeSubstitutionsType] = False,
    separator: SomeSubstitutionsType = os.pathsep,
    **kwargs,
) -> None:
    """
    Create an AppendEnvironmentVariable action.

    All parameters can be provided as substitutions.
    A substitution for the prepend parameter will be coerced to `bool` following YAML rules.

    :param name: the name of the environment variable
    :param value: the value to set or append
    :param prepend: whether the value should be prepended instead
    :param separator: the separator to use, defaulting to a platform-specific separator
    """

But as far as I can tell, the generated API documentation is not hosted anywhere. I'm talking about the output from Sphinx or doxygen that would contain all the information from all the docstrings in the code.
Is it hosted somewhere that I haven't been able to find? Or is the expectation that we should be reading source code to view docstrings?


But as far as I can tell, the generated API documentation is not hosted anywhere. I'm talking about the output from Sphinx or doxygen that would contain all the information from all the docstrings in the code.

I do think maybe the Sphinx docs haven't been rendered for launch.
They are for (at least some) C++ packages:
https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/p/rclcpp/generated/
There's a ROS Discourse thread API documentation issues here.
From this comment

The building process is done by rosdoc2. There are several known issues (like python generation) that are being worked on when possible. And there is also a level that we need maintainers to help to check their documentation build results and provide the necessary metadata.

I think maybe this is just an open issue for launch: https://github.com/ros2/launch/issues/513
